# Can i use query_posts in metabox?

Tags: wordpress, reset

Do you know if it's possible to use query_posts() inside a metabox.

I've tried everything, but can't seem to reset the query properly.

Cheers,

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but you should not. Use get_posts() instead. It is same but does not affect main loop.
From wp codex:

> The query_posts function is intended to be used to modify the main
>   page Loop only. It is not intended as
>   a means to create secondary Loops on
>   the page. If you want to create
>   separate Loops outside of the main
>   one, you should use get_posts()
>   instead. Use of query_posts on Loops
>   other than the main one can result in
>   your main Loop becoming incorrect and
>   possibly displaying things that you
>   were not expecting.